# Error when traversing the matrix in a spiral, starting from the central element

Tags: c++

What is the error in the loops. For example, with a 4x4 matrix, starting at element 13 of the array new_matrix[13] gives incorrect values. With other dimensions matrices the same error.

```
int *helix_center (int** matrix, int size) {
  int* new_matrix = new int[size * size];
  int count = 0;
  int step = 1;
  int sup_var = size / 2;
  int sup_var_2 = sup_var;
  new_matrix[count] = matrix[sup_var][sup_var_2];
  count++;
  while( step < size ) { 
    for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
      if (sup_var_2 != 0)
        new_matrix[count] = matrix[sup_var][--sup_var_2];
      count++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
      if(sup_var != 0) 
        new_matrix[count] = matrix[--sup_var][sup_var_2];
      count++;
    }
    step++;
    for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
      new_matrix[count] = matrix[sup_var][++sup_var_2];
      count++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
      new_matrix[count] = matrix[++sup_var][sup_var_2];
      count++;
    }
    step++;
  }
 return new_matrix;
}
```

Comment: Consider: In the first `for` loop, what gets stored in `new_matrix[count]` when `sup_var_2 == 0`?

Comment: I don't know, what _is_ the error in the loops? You haven't said what actual problem you have, what the symptoms are, what you expected instead or how to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce it, added some simple main with additional prints:

```
#include <iostream>

int* helix_center(int matrix[4][4], int size)
{
    int* new_matrix = new int[size * size];
    int count = 0;
    int step = 1;
    int sup_var = size / 2;
    int sup_var_2 = sup_var;
    new_matrix[count] = matrix[sup_var][sup_var_2];
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    count++;
    while (step < size) {
        for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
            std::cout << count << std::endl;
            if (sup_var_2 != 0)
                new_matrix[count] = matrix[sup_var][--sup_var_2];
            count++;
        }
        std::cout << "=====" << std::endl;
        for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
            std::cout << count << std::endl;
            if (sup_var != 0)
                new_matrix[count] = matrix[--sup_var][sup_var_2];
            count++;
        }
        std::cout << "=====" << std::endl;
        step++;
        for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
            std::cout << count << std::endl;
            new_matrix[count] = matrix[sup_var][++sup_var_2];
            count++;
        }
        std::cout << "=====" << std::endl;
        for (int j = 0; ((j < step) && (step < size)); j++) {
            std::cout << count << std::endl;
            new_matrix[count] = matrix[++sup_var][sup_var_2];
            count++;
        }
        step++;
    }
    return new_matrix;
}

int main()
{
    int matrix[4][4] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 }, { 13, 14, 15, 16 } };
    int* output = helix_center(matrix, 4);
    std::cout << output[13] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Code yields the following:

```
0
1
=====
2
=====
3
4
=====
5
6
7
8
9
=====
10
11
12
=====
=====
1414422387
```

So, as you can see, we never go past 12, thus these indices are not being initialized. Quite a lot going on in your code, kinda hard to track counter's changes.

Here's a great implementation of what you're trying to do:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33701500/5430833

Tweaked it a bit so instead of printing, it puts values to the output buffer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

int* print_spiral (int** matrix, int size)
{
    int* new_matrix = new int[size * size];
    int x = 0; // current position; x
    int y = 0; // current position; y
    int d = 0; // current direction; 0=RIGHT, 1=DOWN, 2=LEFT, 3=UP
    int c = 0; // counter
    int s = 1; // chain size

    // starting point
    x = ((int)floor(size/2.0))-1;
    y = ((int)floor(size/2.0))-1;

    for (int k=1; k<=(size-1); k++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<(k<(size-1)?2:3); j++)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<s; i++)
            {
                new_matrix[c] = matrix[x][y];
                c++;

                switch (d)
                {
                    case 0: y = y + 1; break;
                    case 1: x = x + 1; break;
                    case 2: y = y - 1; break;
                    case 3: x = x - 1; break;
                }
            }
            d = (d+1)%4;
        }
        s = s + 1;
    }
    return new_matrix;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{ { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 }, { 13, 14, 15, 16 } };
    int **p = new int *[v.size()];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) p[i] = v[i].data();
    int* output = print_spiral(p, 4);
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        std::cout << output[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which yields the following:

```
6
7
11
10
9
5
1
2
3
4
8
12
16
15
14
0
```

Which is what you expect, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, but this code only works for odd matrices (3x3.5x5 ...)

Comment: But in my attached example you can see it's 4x4...