# Spiral matrix skip element

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

How can we loop in a matrix anti clockwise, starting at (0,0) and determine what would be the last element in the traversal? Not it can be an NxM matrix.

Comment: I think you start by doing a few examples by hand. Square and rectangular. Even and odd values for `M` and `N`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33688562/2521214

Answer (score 0):

- Travers the matrix in anticlockwise direction with 4 pointers i.e the regular method.
- left, right = 0, col
- top, bottom = 0, row
- Maintain a constraint to [add in result if the index is even else skip], for current side traversal.
- If the last element in current side traversal is not taken, switch the logic to [add in res if odd else skip]
- here is the code :

def anti_clock_spiral_skpi_hop(d):

```
left, right = 0, d[0].__len__()
top, bottom = 0, d.__len__()
ans = []

steps = 0  # flag to control the switch between odd and even index

while left < right and top < bottom:

    # traverse down
    for i in range(top, bottom, 1):
        if (steps + i) % 2 == 0:  # initailly taken even index
            ans.append(d[i][left])
        else:
            # if last element not taken, swithc logic to take odd, hence steps + 1, (because even + 1 = odd)
            if i == bottom - 1:
                steps += 1
    left += 1

    # travers right
    for i in range(left, right, 1):
        if (steps + i) % 2 == 0:
            ans.append(d[bottom - 1][i])
        else:
            if i == right - 1:
                steps += 1
    bottom -= 1

    if not (top < bottom and left < right):
        break


    for i in range(bottom - 1, top - 1, -1):
        if (steps + i) % 2 ==0:
            ans.append(d[i][right - 1])
        else:
            if i == top:
                steps += 1
    right -= 1

    for i in range(right - 1, left - 1, -1):
        if (steps + i) % 2 == 0:
            ans.append(d[top][i])
        else:
            if i == left:
                steps += 1
    top += 1


return ans
```